# Selected tab's color in Bottom Navigation View remain unchanged

Tags: java, android, colors

I'm adding a BottomNavigationView to a project, and I would like to have a different text (and icon tint) color for the selected tab (to achieve greying out non-selected tabs effect). I used a color selector resource file with android:state_checked="true" and it worked fine until I implemented the BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener to one of my Fragment class. After adding that Listener the tab which was selected by default, remains highlighted even if I select a different tab. I tried different attributes to the state selector but nothing is helping.

Here is how I add the view to my layout:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/profileNavBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorLavander"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_color"
        app:menu="@menu/profile_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

Here is my color selector .xml file:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:color="@color/colorWhite" android:state_checked="true" />
        <item android:color="@color/colorInactive" />
    </selector>
```

And here is my Fragment class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import org.home.com.gvwrev.R;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.profileNavBar);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        displayRevFragment(new RecordRevFragment());
    }

    public void displayRevFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.revenueContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.itemRecord:
                fragment = new RecordRevFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.itemModify:
                fragment = new ModifyRevFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.itemView:
                break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            displayRevFragment(fragment);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/ultimate-guide-to-bottom-navigation-on-android-75e4efb8105f
https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should `return true` when an item is selected in `onNavigationItemSelected` method. Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.itemRecord:
            fragment = new RecordRevFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.itemModify:
            fragment = new ModifyRevFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.itemView:
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        displayRevFragment(fragment);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```